# utf-8 character printing in matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, utf-8, seaborn

I have utf-8(hindi) word vectors and want to visualize. it using t-SNE and I am using annotate method of matplotlib to plot words.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [1,2]
y = [4,2]
hindi_word = [u'के', u'है']
for i, txt in enumerate(hindi_word):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]))

ax.scatter(x,y)
```

It shows boxes instead of actual words 'के', 'है' as attached in below image. How to print actual utf-8 words instead of boxes.

[image: output image]

Comment: Try to add `#encoding: utf-8` at the beginning of py file.

Comment: This is a matplotlib problem, not a python problem, so `#encoding: utf-8` does not help.

Comment: Usually boxes mean that the font used doesn't define glyphs for the required code points (so it's not an encoding problem sensu stricto). Try specifying a font which covers devanagari. (I don't know by heart how to do it, but I think you need to create a Formatter object or something like that.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the font of the typesetting.
The standard font does not support your desired characters.
I have found a found in matplotlib that does the trick: `Lohit Devanagari`. I'm not sure that this is the only possibility, this was the first that worked.

Before annotating, add this line to change the font:

```
plt.rc('font', family='Lohit Devanagari')
```

Matplotlib now renders the correct characters:

[image: output]